# Split values in MYSQL Column and display in PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL DB with Columns with string values separated by Comma's

**"gpslev":"19","gsmlev":"2","io1":"1","io104":"520","io113":"-21760"**

I want to show the information on a PHP page where I can echo the information using the first part as the identifier and the second part as the information

For Example gpslev (Identifier) 19 (Information to display)

```
<?php
                            $host="localhost"; // Host name
                            $username="root"; // Mysql username
                            $password="****@"; // Mysql password
                            $db_name="****"; // Database name
                            // Connect to server and select database.
                            mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
                            mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
                            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fleet WHERE sla_client = '$slcustom1' ORDER BY reg");
                            ?>
                            <?php
                            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="center"><?php echo $rows['gpslev']; ?>/td> **In this row I need to show GPSLEV value**
                            <?php } ?>
```

The string of data in this row is sent to my DB by a tracking device so I need to split the information into values that I can echo the information/value received.

As the string has about 30 - 40 values I want to select the value according to the identifier

io1 or io113 each one has different values I want to show in a field or table

Comment: _"I need to split the information into values that I can echo"_ Please post the code you have written so far to do this.

Comment: [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on the comma and then `explode()` each result on de colon.

Comment: @Michel if I explode each and then explode again on the : I have to assign each a value and with 30 plus values this will make a long code of explosions. Is there no other way where I can use the gpslev as identifier in the string to echo the value to a table or field

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to return an `array` populated as `$array['gpslev'] = "19";`

```
function populateArrayFromString($string)
{
    $array = [];
    $pairs = explode(",", $string);
    foreach($pairs as $pair) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(":", $pair);
        $arrayToReturn[trim($key, '"')] = trim($value, '"');
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Now you can use it in your loop:

```
<?php

function populateArrayFromString($string)
{
    $array = [];
    $pairs = explode(",", $string);
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(":", $pair);
        $arrayToReturn[trim($key, '"')] = trim($value, '"');
    }

    return $array;
}

$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "root"; // Mysql username
$password = "****@"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "****"; // Database name
// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fleet WHERE sla_client = '$slcustom1' ORDER BY reg");
?>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data = populateArrayFromString($row['string_column_name']);
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $data['gpslev']; ?></td> **In this row I need to show GPSLEV value**
    <?php } ?>
```